# How to enable keyboard accessibility via spacebar for radio buttons and check boxes in angular 2

Tags: angular, accessibility, angular-material2

I have a form in angular 2.The form has radio buttons and check boxes.On tabbing, the fields are getting highlighted.For radio buttons I want them to get selected once i hit spacebar.Same for check boxes. I am using the snippet from angular 2 material design.

```
<md-radio-group>
<md-radio-button value="" name="">Yes</md-radio-button>
<md-radio-button value="" [checked]="true" name="">No</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

In my component.ts file-

```
import {component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
export class Components implements OnInit {

// The logic below
}
```

I want the "No" option to be default selected on page load but that's not happening.Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong?

Also, in case of checkboxes,onc its checked on hitting spacebar next time that should get unchecked wen I hit spacebar.That's not happening.It just gets selected.
code for checkbox selection via spacebar in my component.ts-

```
handleKeyUp($event,checkBox: MdCheckBox){
    if ($event.code===32){
    checkBox.checked=true;
    }
}
```

Two way data binding is not happening.Appreciate the help.Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you cannot just use `input type=radio||checkbox` and wire it up with Angular bits? Then they can operate the way users expect, especially if it is different than using a space bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and put a `(keyup)="handleKeyup($event)"` handler on your `<md-radio-button>` and in the `handleKeyup` method, check if the spacebar was pressed. You would also need to pass the currently focused radio-button as a template variable, so it can be selected in your controller.

For example in your template:

```
<md-radio-group>
   <md-radio-button #rdo1 value="" name="" (keyup)="handleKeyup($event, rdo1)">Yes</md-radio-button>
   <md-radio-button #rdo2 value="" name="" (keyup)="handleKeyup($event, rdo2)>No</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

In your controller.ts:

```
import { MdRadioButton } from '@angular/material/radio';

export class Component implements OnInit {

   constructor() { }

   handleKeyup($event, radio: MdRadioButton) {
      if($event.code === 32) { // spacebar
         radio.checked = true;
      }
   }

}
```

Update:

To set 'NO' as the selected radio-button on startup you need to do this in your template:

```
<md-radio-group selected=rdo2>
   <md-radio-button #rdo1 value="" name="" (keyup)="handleKeyup($event, rdo1)">Yes</md-radio-button>
   <md-radio-button #rdo2 value="" name="" (keyup)="handleKeyup($event, rdo2)>No</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

Comment: Alexander Ciesielski same for checkboxes?

Comment: Should be the same, yes.

Comment: I am writing the logic inside export class MdRadioButton.But this throws error.

Comment: You should put that code in your component's controller .ts file.

Comment: Yeah already doing that.Does the sequence matter as the .ts file has multiple import and export statement.

Comment: Please update your question with your controller's code.

Comment: You should update your own question, not my answer.
I have updated my answer with more code.

Comment: That was a mistake.With the above code I am getting error as -

Comment: 1.Class 'Components' incorrectly implements interface 'onInit'

Comment: I had to include ngOnInit().The error is gone now but the keyboard accesibility via spacebar is still not working.

Comment: Working fine.Thanks a ton!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125601/discussion-between-techie-questie-and-alexander-ciesielski).

Comment: How can I make 'No' option as the default selected one on page load.

Comment: You have to set on the second radio-button `checked = true`

Comment: I am adding checked=true in my html file directly but that's not reflecting.Is checked=true accepted in material design?

Comment: For checkboxes, the check and uncheck should happen consecutively.That's not happening right now for checkboxes. Please see the code I have added for checkboxes.

Comment: I need the radio button functionality in multiple pages wherever we have radio buttons.How can I do that in angular 2?